# How to add image in javascript i have been trying to fetch it through this api

Tags: javascript

How to add image in javascript i have been trying to fetch it through this api i have been trying to solve this i'm new to learning javascript so please help me understand it so i can move ahead further
How can I solve this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<strong>Name</strong>
    <div id = "Name" ></div>
    <strong>Eye Colour:</strong><div id = "eye_colour"></div>
    <strong>Hey:</strong>   <div id="hey"></div>
    <strong>Image</strong><div id="img"> </div>
    <button class="randomName">Randomize</button>
    <button class="downloadImage">Download Image</button>
</body>   
    <script>
        const name = document.getElementById("Name")
        const eye_colour = document.getElementById("eye_colour")
        const hey = document.getElementById("hey")
       const button = document.querySelector('.randomName');
       button.addEventListener("click", (e) =>{
            e.preventDefault()
            Name.innerHTML ='<em>Loading....</em>'
            eye_colour.innerHTML= '<em>Loading....</em>'
            hey.innerHTML = '<em>Loading....</em>'
            // console.log("clicked")
            const randomNumber= Math.ceil(Math.random() * 83)
        fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/people/${randomNumber}`)
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(CharacterData =>{
            // console.log(CharacterData)
            Name.innerHTML =CharacterData['name']
            eye_colour.innerHTML= CharacterData['eye_color']
            hey.innerHTML = CharacterData['birth_year']
        })
        const another_Button = document.querySelector('.downloadImage')
        another_Button.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
            const image = getElementById('img')
        const randomId = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 88)
        fetch(`https://akabab.github.io/starwars-api/api/all.json`)
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(idData =>{
            image.innerHTML = idData['image']
        })
        })
        })
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not a [mcve] (and please proof-read your question and fix any problems with the [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) _before_ you submit it)

Comment: I think you are looking for `image.src = idData['image']`

Answer (score 0):

You should update your `fetch` function on success like the below:

```js
fetch(`https://akabab.github.io/starwars-api/api/all.json`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(idData => {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = idData['image'];
    document.getElementById('img').appendChild(img);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

use document.createElement to add image
Sample code

```
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = 'https://imageurl.jpg';
    document.getElementById('anyParentTagId').appendChild(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an img tag for this. There you can set the src attribute to the image URL from the API.

```js
document.getElementById('img').src= "https://placekitten.com/400/300"
```

```html
<img id="img">
```

currently you are using a div tag